# Bash shell iterations over letters and numbers

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, scripting

Say I want to iterate over two lists of letters and numbers.
`A B C D` and `seq 1 100`.
How can I iterate over letters along with numbers but not as in nested for-loop? So it would be `A1B2C3D4 A5B6C7D8 ...`

What I've tried so far: nested for-loop and `& done` don't seem to be of any help, since they produce either `A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2...` or inconsistent results of parallel execution.

Also it feels like a very basic parallel loop, so **no need for a detailed explanation or actual code**: ANY ANSWER mentioning link to docs or the conventional name of such sequence would be immediately accepted.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks for question I tried for-loop and `& done` but wasn't able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: The best would be to show your code

Comment: It wouldn't be Z25. There are A, B, C, D only.

Comment: If it loops over A-D and doesn't break the numbers loop, then it's exactly what I need. `A1B2C3D4 A5B6C7D8 ...` and so on.

Comment: Nested loops as I understand give out `A1A2A3...A100 B1B2B3...`, etc. This is not what I need actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script generates your expected output with a leading space:

**Script**

```
for i in {1..100}; do
    IFS= read c
    printf %s "$c$i"
done < <(yes $' A\nB\nC\n\D')
```

**Output**

```
 A1B2C3D4 A5B6C7D8 A9B10C11D12 A13B14C15D16 A17B18C19D20 A21B22C23D24 A25B26C27D28 A29B30C31D32 A33B34C35D36 A37B38C39D40 A41B42C43D44 A45B46C47D48 A49B50C51D52 A53B54C55D56 A57B58C59D60 A61B62C63D64 A65B66C67D68 A69B70C71D72 A73B74C75D76 A77B78C79D80 A81B82C83D84 A85B86C87D88 A89B90C91D92 A93B94C95D96 A97B98C99D100
```

**Explanation**

To read the sequence `1 2 3 ... 100` in its full length, we need to repeat the sequence `A B C D` over and over again. `yes` is a command that repeats its argument ad infinitum. `yes x` prints

```
x
x
x
...
```

To let `yes` print something different in every line, we use a trick. `$' A\nB\nC\nD'` is a string that contains linebreaks (`$''` is a so called bash ansi-c quote). `yes $' A\nB\nC\nD'` will print

```
 A
B
C
D
 A
B
...
```

Instead of printing to the console, we want to consume the text later. To this end, we could write `yes ... | someCommand` or `someCommand < <(yes ...)` which has some advantages over a pipe. The latter is called [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst). Note that `for ...; done` is also just one command. The redirected stdin can be read from anywhere inside the `for` loop.

Comment: This is what I need! Could you please describe what does this part do essentially `done < <(yes...`

Comment: Glad to hear that. I'll add a explanation. One moment please.

Comment: You are the man! Despite all obstacles of newbie posting it's great to have here such people with well written and concise answers. Thanks again!

Comment: Just curious: is there any conventional name of such looping in programming?

Comment: Not that I would know. Maybe in functional programming, where you would consider both sequences as streams, the loop would be replaced by a zip or merge operation -- an operation that computes one stream based on two others. The nearest thing to that in bash is the `paste` command combined with some subsequent operations.

Comment: Actually I find this piece of code very useful. I've already implemented your solution inside my actual code with like no  efforts. I wasn't able to find similar questions by regular queries as for-loop, iterations, pipes, sequences, etc., so I  think that downvoting was due to my unclear explanations. So I hope this answer will be upvoted as much as possible, because the answer might be very useful for newbies. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# ASCII code for A
A=65

# Loop from 1 to 100
for ii in $( seq 1 100 )
do
    # Compute ASCII code with using modulo
    code=$(( (ii-1) % 4 + A ))

    # Print letter
    printf "\x$(printf %x $code)"

    # Print number
    echo $ii
done
```

Comment: For future individuals, it would be nice if this answer explained why it works.

Comment: @KevinO Seriously?  I commented every single line.  What is not explained?

Comment: Yes, seriously. Why does modulo work to answer the question. Obviously the loop is commented, but the main logic that solves the problem is not explained.

Comment: If someone does not understand how the modulo operator works, then I might as well assume he does not know how to program at all.